# How cannot I install a Google Chrome App I developed myself?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have created a Google Chrome App and published in webstore, but not listed.

When I go to this URL:

`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-app/thisistheid?hl=en`

This appears in the installation button:

[image: Not compatible button]

However, during development, I could install the application manually.

What is wrong here?

EDIT:

This is the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "App Name",
  "description": "blablabla.",
  "version": "1.1",
  "permissions": [

  ],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "main.js" ]
    }
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [ "*://localhost:*/*" ]
  },
  "sockets": {
    "tcp": {
      "connect": "localhost:1437"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "32": "img/icon32.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png",
    "128": "img/icon128.png"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "img/logo.jpg" ]
}
```

Comment: You made this app only for Chrome os compatible

Comment: So, how I can install it manually?

Comment: Chrome OS is an operating system. Google Chrome is a web browser. It appears that you've made an app for the Chrome OS operating system not for the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: @Quantic I know the difference, but why can I install it manually? Did you see the manifest.json file in the question? That manifest.json is for Chrome App for a web browser, AFAIK.

Comment: Well, you can't. The apps were deprecated long time ago, now they disallowed web store installation, and in 2022 the corresponding code will be totally removed from Chrome so you won't be able to run it even locally. See the [announcement](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/moving-forward-from-chrome-apps.html).